# Accounting for uncertainty in a fit coefficient

Tags: monte-carlo, measurement-error, error-propagation

So given some empirical data of $I_T$ vs $r$ I'd like to fit that to some model given by
$$
I_T=\frac{I_0}{1+F \sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi d}{\lambda}\frac{f}{f^2+r^2}\bigg)}
$$I am trying to analyze data from a Fabry-Perot interferometer where I measure the intensity profile of light from a helium neon laser in order to calibrate it to measure the hyperfine structure of mercury's green transition line.

So, I have the following image,
[image]
which has a radial intensity profile that looks like 
[image]

My goal is to then fit that intnesity profile to the following function, which is supposed to describe these ring patterns from a FP interferometer
$$
I_T=\frac{I_0}{1+F \sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi d}{\lambda}\frac{f}{f^2+r^2}\bigg)}
$$
where $I_T$ is intensity at a given value of $r$, $F$ is known as the coefficient of finesse which is related to the resolving power of the interferometer, $d$ is the plate separation of the interferometer, $f$ is the focal length of the lens I've used and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of my helium neon laser.

I have measurements of $\lambda$ and $f$. So, I would like to fit for $d$ and $F$. The concern I have run into though, is that I realize now that my measurement of $f$ has a huge amount of experimental error in it and I'd like to account for that in my fit, however I don't really understand how. My knowledge of curve fitting has only informed me of what do to with errors in my measurements of $I_T$ and $r$.

I sense a couple ways to deal with this but would like some advice on the best way to proceed. One thing to do is Monte-Carlo simulations. I could run the fit 1000 times for $f$ and $\lambda$ with a gaussian error in them with width proportional to my estimate of their uncertainty, and then measure the variance of the set of Monte-Carlo fit parameters for $d$. This seems like a bit of a pain in the neck, but also doable.

Another approach would be to propagate my estimated error in $f$ into my estimated error in $I_T$, ie. do the following transformation to my estimated error in $I_T$ 
$$
\delta I_t \rightarrow \sqrt{(\delta I_T)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial I_T}{\partial f}\delta f\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial I_T}{\partial \lambda}\delta \lambda\bigg)^2} 
$$
and then just weigh my data by this transformed uncertainty in my fit.

I'm wondering if any of you have opinions on which of these is the 'better' method here.

I understand that subjective questions are discouraged here, so let me phrase this as follows: Should the two methods I discussed give the same or similar results? Why or why not? Is there a more correct or less labour intensive way to account for error $f$?

I have measurements of $\lambda$ and $f$. So, I would like to fit for $d$. The concern I have run into though, is that I realize now that my measurement of $f$ has a huge amount of experimental error in it and I'd like to account for that in my fit, however I don't really understand how. My knowledge of curve fitting has only informed me of what do to with errors in my measurements of $I_T$ and $r$.

I sense a couple ways to deal with this but would like some advice on the best way to proceed. One thing to do is Monte-Carlo simulations. I could run the fit 1000 times for $f$ and $\lambda$ with a gaussian error in them with width proportional to my estimate of their uncertainty, and then measure the variance of the set of Monte-Carlo fit parameters for $d$. This seems like a bit of a pain in the neck, but also doable.

Another approach would be to propagate my estimated error in $f$ into my estimated error in $I_T$, ie. do the following transformation to my estimated error in $I_T$ 
$$
\delta I_t \rightarrow \sqrt{(\delta I_T)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial I_T}{\partial f}\delta f\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{\partial I_T}{\partial \lambda}\delta \lambda\bigg)^2} 
$$
and then just weigh my data by this transformed uncertainty in my fit.

I'm wondering if any of you have opinions on which of these is the 'better' method here.

I understand that subjective questions are discouraged here, so let me phrase this as follows: Should the two methods I discussed give the same or similar results? Why or why not? Is there a more correct or less labour intensive way to account for error $f$?

Comment: Would you clarify the *experimental design* a bit? How are your measurements indexed? For example, do you have a separate measurement of $\lambda$ and $f$ for each experimental unit, or just single measurements that correspond to the experimental apparatus? (Also, mainly for general interest but also to help with concreteness: Does your formula for $I_T$ have a standard name? What is the experimental setting?)

Comment: @DavidC.Norris Just a single measurement of $\lambda$ and $f$ for the apparatus. I'll update the question to include more info on the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your problem the best approach approach is to fit the following model with the parameters $I_0$, d, F, $\lambda$, f. 
You adopt a prior on $\lambda$, $f$ that is given by the current measurements that you have:
$ \lambda \sim N(\lambda_0, \sigma_\lambda^2) $ 
$ f \sim N(f_0, \sigma_f^2) $
And then you have a Gaussian likelihood on the rings intensities. 
$ I_i|r_i ~ \sim N(\frac{I_0}{1+F sin(\frac{2\pi d}{\lambda}\frac{f}{f^2+r_i^2})}, e_i^2) $ where $I_i$ are the measurements of the intensity at the radius $r_i$ and uncertainty $e_i$. Than you can MCMC sample the posterior. The 1D marginal posteriors on d and F will properly reflect the uncertainty on f, $\lambda$.

Comment: I concur with @sega_sai. Because of the way $f$ enters into your formula, the radial intensity profile could conceivably contain a great deal of information about $f$. So your 'rough estimate' of $f$ (embodied in the prior) might just serve to get the MCMC started. Another thing to consider (if you can derive an appropriate formula) would be whether the *image itself* (is it affected by some kind of alignment issue or other optical imperfection?) contains useful information over and above the radial profile you plotted.

Comment: Okay, this is along the lines I was thinking, though I do need a bit of clarification if you don't mind as I'm something of a neophyte to this sort of data analysis. First off, do  you mind clarifying what you mean by $ \lambda \sim N(\lambda_0, \sigma_\lambda^2) $ 
$ f \sim N(f_0, \sigma_f^2) $ and $ I_i|r_i ~ \sim N(\frac{I_0}{1+F sin(\frac{2\pi d}{\lambda}\frac{f}{f^2+r_i^2})}, e_i^2) $ as this is notation I'm not wholly familiar with and I don't want to misinterpret you.

Comment: $X\sim N(a,b^2)$ means that  X is normally distributed with mean a and variance $b^2$. And each of the terms I listed will reflect a term in the posterior. I.e. For the listed example, the log-posterior that you need to sample will be $$-0.5 ( (\frac{\lambda-\lambda_0}{\sigma_\lambda})^2 + (\frac{f-f_0}{\sigma_f})^2 + \sum_i (\frac{Model(r_i)-I_i}{e_i})^2$$